# Attaching the on() method to a jquery selector

Tags: jquery

I am trying to attach several events to a JQuery selector by using the `on()` method, but with no success. The error I am receiving is:

`TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'on'`.

My code is as follows:

```
var input = $("<input type=\"text\" class=\"textboxes\" id=\"option-1\">");
input.on('change keyup blur', function() {
    console.log('event fired');
});
return input;
```

Any help please?

Comment: What version of jQuery do you have? To use jQuery `.on()` you must have version 1.7+ https://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: I'm using 1.4, so that in itself answers my question. on() is only supported from 1.7. Totally missed that. Thanks anyway Anton

Comment: @RudolfLamprecht you should really upgrade it to at least 1.10

Comment: Update your jQuery and you can do this -> http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/XKGA9/

Comment: Company policy Rory, have a stack of clients running on old versions of our product, so upgrading the framework is a big no no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using jQuery version 1.4, you can make use of **[.delegate()](https://api.jquery.com/delegate/)** instead:

```
$("body").delegate(input,"change keyup blur", function() {
    console.log('event fired');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var input = $("<input type=\"text\" class=\"textboxes\" id=\"option-1\">");
```

The above code will create a input element,but will not append it to the DOM.
Instead,retrieve the element using $('#option-1') and then bind it using on() event.